# I am having trouble accessing the MySql server

Tags: passwords, mysql, database

I am using HeidiSQL to connect to my MySql servers. On the machines in which I configured I can connect without problems to the Mysql server. But in the case of this one that was not the one that I set up is giving the problem of:

```
Access denied for user 'fgc'@'10.20.8.16' (using password: NO)
```

Since I have already provided and have already changed the password and tried to delete and recreate the user and still give the same error. I have no idea what can be and can not find in forums. Could someone give me a light?

Comment: If your account has a password, your client isn't using it because it says **using password:NO).**  Therefore, you need to get the client to use the password, otherwise you can't login to an account that has a password.

Comment: Additionally, you'll need to make sure that A) the server is listening on the correct interface, and B) the user is permitted to authenticate from a remote system.